# Android Device Admin

Tags: android, device-admin

I want to use my app in Kiosk mode according to [this](http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-kiosk-mode-without-root/)

So I added a receiver into my manifest, created the class and installed the app on my tablet. But after 2 factory resets and no account on this tablet I still get this error message when executing the device admin command:

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner packageName/.AdminReceiver

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to set device owner but device is already provisioned.
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
    android:name="packageName.AdminReceiver"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.device_admin"
        android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

This command has to be run during device setup. After device setup Google becomes default device owner if no other device owner is specified and a device can only have 1 device owner.